# Store and read a file in a sqlite3 database with SQLAlchemy in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to store and read a file (e.g. `myfile.dat`) from my hard drive into a sqlite3 database accessing over SQLAlchemy with Python3.

I want to store one picture for each row of Person-table. I just want to show that picture in a GUI when the data of that Person are shown.

Comment: Can you eloborate why? Usually files are stored separately, as SQLite is not optimized for this purpose.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Please see the updated question-text. I don't know which optimizations there should be. A files is data. A database is to store data. I see no problem.

Comment: Most Python frameworks (Django) do this so that they they store the file on the the disk. Each file gots random id. In the database they only store a reference to this file: random file id and possibly the original filename.

Comment: If database grows size when you toss in files there normal database operations, not touching the file data, may suffer too.

Comment: That's why usually people want to keep files out of databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply read the file in binary-mode from hard drive and store it as a BLOB to the database.

```
 with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
     fcontent = f.read()
```

Get the BLOB (as `image`) from database and feed it to a Python-byte stream.
Then you can use it e.g. as a *Stream-Object* in wxPython.

```
 # read the BLOB as 'image' from database
 # and use it
 stream = io.BytesIO(image)
 image = wx.Image(stream)
 bitmap = wx.Bitmap(image)
```